# How to insert new line Char(13) in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have applied XML PATH and Stuff to show multiple records in single cell, which is all working fine but I am required to show each record in cell in separate single line i.e char(13) but in my solution I am getting result like

```
   #x0D;; Canvey&#x0D;; government&#x0D;; More information needed&#x0D;; More information required
```

Script

```
 SELECT 
  ans.Id 
 ,ans.ResponseId
,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT
 char(13)+char(10) +
 '; ' + cod.Name
 ,' ' + COUNT(cod.Name)
FROM [dbo].[Highlights] as h
INNER JOIN [dbo].[CodedHighlights] as ch on h.Id = ch.HighlightId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Codes] as cod on ch.CodeId = cod.Id
WHERE h.AnswerId = ans.Id
GROUP BY cod.Name
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' ) [ANSWER/CODES]
FROM [dbo].[Answers] as ans
```

Comment: Note that `CHAR(10)` and/or `CHAR(13)` may not display as you expect if you are running this query directly in management studio.

Comment: you need to pass `TYPE` to `XML PATH` to get an XML typed result then call `.value` on that. If you had provided a full MCVE I would have given you the exact code but as you haven't I won't (as too much hassle to validate it is correct)

Comment: You have 2 columns being returned in your subquery, what are you expecting there? acomma between the 2 values, the values simply concatenated?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(100)=
STUFF(
    (
        SELECT TOP 5 CHAR(13) + [name]
        FROM sys.objects 
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');

PRINT @result;
```

You must use `TYPE` to get a natively typed XML in order to use the `.value()` method. This will implicitly re-escape all entities to their actual string values.

Furthermore, I use `PRINT`, as the typical grid result would not show the line breaks.

Hint: If you use `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)` you'd have to add `,1,2,'')` as `STUFF()`'s paramaters.